# appcelerator connect to nodejs https REST

Tags: https, httprequest, appcelerator

I try to connect to my rest api on a nodejs server deployed in https.
I have a self-signed certificate installed on my server.

I did not understand the appcelerator documentation to configure my certifcat in the httprequest. Only documentation for the https module.
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Https

Only for a pro subscription O_o damn ! I must be rich to be secure ?? ;)

**Here is the code :**

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    validatesSecureCertificate:true,
    onload: function() {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    },
    onerror : function(e) {
         console.log(e.error);
     },
     timeout : 5000
});

xhr.open('GET','https://xx.xx.xx.xxx:443/test');
xhr.send();
```

**The answer :**

The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “xx.xx.xx.xxx” which could put your confidential information at risk.

Thank's for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not unique to Appcelerator Titanium or any other mobile solution.  The problem is your cert.  Try using something like Cloudflare (free)  https://www.cloudflare.com/  to get a secure SSL connection instead of doing it with a self-signed cert like that.

Comment: I've installed a valid cert, but now the problem is " the server doesn't exist"